# Lightswitch when inserting get current values

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

So I want to create a project number when a new project is created, based on a few variables entered on the 'new project screen' I.E. controlling office.

I at first put the code on the changed rule of the office variable, but now I want to move it to the inserting code on the entity so it is run no matter how the record is created.

How to I reference the data being inserted from the entity_inserting code?
This.controllingoffice and this.projectnumber don't work. How can i get a reference to what values are about to be inserted, and manipulate them??

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that ControllingOffice and ProjectNumber are values defined by a screen?  If so, then your logic is completely dependent on the screen and can't be implemented in the Inserting method of the entity because that is executed on the server tier and has no access to screen data.  If the data of the project is coming from the screen, then you need to set that data from the screen.  If this isn't what you're doing, then please explain further, specifically where are you getting the ControllingOffice and ProjectNumber data values.

Comment: Ah ok, I was under the impression the inserting method would be passed the screen data to insert, but if that has no access to screen data then that makes sense. 
So the correct behavior is to do this on the screen itself, and then copy and paste this code onto the saving method of every screen that needs to create a new project number?

Comment: Yep, basically.  Just define a common helper method that initializes the state of the Project entity and have those screens call it, passing in the ControllingOffice and ProjectNumber.